# Can I transit through Frankfurt to Romania without a Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, romania, fra

I am applying for a Romanian Short Stay Visa. I have a valid US visa. I am travelling from the US to Romania. Typically, I would need a Schengen Visa if I need to go to a Schengen Zone as my nationality is Indian. 
My flight is US - Frankfurt - Romania. Can I transit through Frankfurt to Romania without a Schengen visa?

I see most answers from this link [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area) 
But what I am not sure is:

2. Can you transfer without leaving the international area of the airport?

Question: Can I go to a Romania from Frankfurt without leaving the international area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, because, as of June 2015, Romania is not (yet) part of the Schengen area (they almost certainly won't be in the next few months but they are supposed to join some time in the future). It's best to have a short layover and to book the whole trip at once to make sure you won't have to collect your luggage in Frankfurt but sterile transit is otherwise not a problem, even at night.

Incidentally, you probably already figured out that your US visa exempts you from the airside transit visa requirement in Germany but your Romanian visa would also be enough so you have not only one but two ways to qualify for this exemption!

Comment: Perfect. Yes, I am travelling this June.
Thanks for that quick response. That is what I am trying to do. Book them all in the same ticket/itinerary. I have a stop of 3+ hrs in Frankfurt while going and coming.